# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMediaElementSource' of null

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Hello I have a project javaScript and it's new for me, I work with the audio web API, the code allows me to play music and stop with the same button all seems good but the console displays this message error please anyone can help me to solve this problem and if you have another problem please tell me tnx.

that is the problem

> (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMediaElementSource'
>   of null
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (h1.html?_ijt=o00si3cs9lv3ovov0so3fv3a4h:33) (anonymous) @
>   h1.html?_ijt=o00si3cs9lv3ovov0so3fv3a4h:33).

this is my code:

```
 <html>
<body>
<section class="tape">

    <audio src="outfoxing.mp3" crossorigin="anonymous" ></audio>

    <!--            type="audio/mpeg" -->

    <button data-playing="false" class="tape-controls-play" role="switch" aria-checked="false">
        <span>Play/Pause</span>
    </button>
</section>
<script>
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext;
    let audioCtx = null;
    //play video
    let playButton = document.querySelector('.tape-controls-play');
    let audioElement =null ;

        playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

          let  track= new AudioContext();
            audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
            audioCtx= audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

        // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
        if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
            audioCtx.resume();
        }

        if (this.dataset.playing === 'false') {
            audioElement.play();
            this.dataset.playing = 'true';
            // if track is playing pause it
        } else if (this.dataset.playing === 'true') {
            audioElement.pause();
            this.dataset.playing = 'false';
        }

        let state = this.getAttribute('aria-checked') === "true" ;
        this.setAttribute( 'aria-checked', state ? "false" : "true" );

// connect our graph
            audioElement.addEventListener('ended', () => {
                playButton.dataset.playing = 'false';
                playButton.setAttribute( "aria-checked", "false" );
                track.connect(audioCtx.destination);
            }, false);

    }, false);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT :**

After editing the code, as suggested by [@chŝdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669624/ch%c5%9ddk) in the answer below, to:

```
audioCtx= track.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

I keep getting the following Warning:

> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page

Ae there any solutions for this issue?

Comment: That's because you are trying to call a function on `audioCtx` while it's still `null` in `audioCtx= audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);`.

Comment: what should i do to resolve that problem

Comment: I wrote an answer for more detailed solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are trying to call `createMediaElementSource` method on a `null` variable `audioCtx` in this line:

```
audioCtx= audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

From the **[`AudioContext.createMediaElementSource()` MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource)**, we can see that this method should be called on a `AudioContext` instance, so in your code you will need to call it on `track` variable instead.

So just change the above line to:

```
audioCtx= track.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185128/discussion-on-answer-by-chsdk-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createme).